# How to find which profile.ps1 file is used for the PowerShell Integrated Console?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

Using PowerShell 5.1 in vscode. There are a lot of profile.ps1 files on my system.

Comment: This will probably enlighten you ;-)  [Understanding the Six PowerShell Profiles](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To know where your profile should be, you can simply query the `$profile` variable:

```
> $profile

> # It might not exist. Then you can just create it
> if (!(Test-Path $profile)) { 
       Write-Host 'Hello from your new profile' > $profile; 
       "Profile file created in $profile" 
  }
```

Comment: Or just `New-Item $PROFILE`

Comment: @Carlos Garcia I'm sure this looks like a simple answer to you but I've spent hours trying to make sure where the colors are coming from. Partly because I've got a bunch of test installs for 5.1, 7, 7.1. and an effort at local install. Thank you for your help Carlos!

Comment: @schuelermine Your answer worked just fine and certainly wins the Ockhem's Razor test however after all I've been through trying to nail this down the reassuring closed loop that Carlos gave got the answer mark.